# Is there any way to make this C switch case more simple?

Tags: c, logistic-regression

I used the logistic-regression model to get a formula. Because I took every hour as a factor, so this switch-case very long, inconvenient to modify, and not beautiful. Is there a way to simplify it? Maybe I should try to use matrices for arithmetic?

```
...
#define elif else if
...
// hours
switch (hours) {
    case 0:
        prob[2] = prob_base[7];
        break;
    case 1:
        prob[2] = prob_base[8];
        break;
    case 2:
        prob[2] = prob_base[9];
        break;
    case 3:
        prob[2] = prob_base[10];
        break;
    case 4:
        prob[2] = prob_base[11];
        break;
    case 5:
        prob[2] = prob_base[12];
        break;
    case 6:
        prob[2] = prob_base[13];
        break;
    case 7:
        prob[2] = prob_base[14];
        break;
    case 8:
        prob[2] = prob_base[15];
        break;
    case 9:
        prob[2] = prob_base[16];
        break;
    case 10:
        prob[2] = prob_base[17];
        break;
    case 11:
        prob[2] = prob_base[18];
        break;
    case 12:
        prob[2] = prob_base[19];
        break;
    case 13:
        prob[2] = prob_base[20];
        break;
    case 14:
        prob[2] = prob_base[21];
        break;
    case 15:
        prob[2] = prob_base[22];
        break;
    case 16:
        prob[2] = prob_base[23];
        break;
    case 17:
        prob[2] = prob_base[24];
        break;
    case 18:
        prob[2] = prob_base[25];
        break;
    case 19:
        prob[2] = prob_base[26];
        break;
    case 20:
        prob[2] = prob_base[27];
        break;
    case 21:
        prob[2] = prob_base[28];
        break;
    case 22:
        prob[2] = prob_base[29];
        break;
    case 23:
        prob[2] = prob_base[30];
        break;
    default:
        prob[2] = 0;
        break;
}

// bidf
prob[3] = prob_base[31] * atof(bidf);

// isp
switch (isp) {
    case 1:
        prob[4] = prob_base[32];
        break;
    case 2:
        prob[4] = prob_base[33];
        break;
    case 3:
        prob[4] = prob_base[34];
        break;
    default:
        prob[4] = 0;
        break;
}
...
```

Comment: arrx[2]=arry[i+7]

Comment: Maybe `prob[2]=prob_base[hours+7]`?

Comment: Off-topic: this should go on code review. By the way, they is no keyword `elif` in C.

Comment: You don't see the pattern here?

Comment: @Stargateur negative, this **definitely** must not go to code review as it doesn't **work**.

Comment: @Stargateur Yes, I add a `#define elif else if` before.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik thank you very much

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès thank you very much

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Sorry, what doesn't work? The forgot `#define elif else if`? This is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
if (hours >= 0 && hours < 24)
  prob[2] = prob_base[hours + 7];
else
  prob[2] = 0;

prob[3] = prob_base[31] * atof(bidf);

if (isp >= 1 && isp < 4)
  prob[4] = prob_base[isp + 31];
else
  prob[4] = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//hours
prob[2] = prob_base[hours+7];          //no switch required
```